# Still booting from old kernel after upgrade

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, grub2, upgrade, kernel

I upgraded 2 almost identical servers from 14.04.2 to 16.04.3 via do-release-upgrade.
One went fine but the other still boots from the old kernel. I tried all suggestions mentioned in similar situations, doing the kernel upgrade again, updating grub etc. but no luck. On the problem server I noticed there is another boot directory inside the /boot which has another grub.cfg and the old kernel and grub is coming from there.
Anyone seen this before? /etc/default/grub points to the normal /boot/grub/grub.cfg which is the new kernel but somehow thats not getting picked up.

Thanks

Comment: This is getting seriously weird. I removed the second boot directory under /boot (it was housing all the old 3.16 kernels) Then I did an apt-get purge of the 3.16 kernel, then updated grub which showed the correct output of kernel 4.4.0-112 (verified manually inside grub.cfg). But the system still boots with kernel 3.16.0-57. No idea where its coming from. Nothing in /boot refers to the old kernel anymore. I also ran locate to find any files but nothing for 3.16.0-57, where is the system picking this up from?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue a few days ago and thought it might be useful to post here as well, in case someone else encounters a similar situation.
I will try to summarize as best as I can as I went through a lot of iterations in figuring it out.

Per my understanding the reason why the machine was booting from an old kernel was because of a previously configured /boot disk which was no longer even mounting (but I realized the bootloader does not really need a mounted disk). At some point in the past an admin had tried to setup a new /boot on a different disk and added it to fstab and removed the old /boot, but I guess things weren't done correctly, hence the problem surfaced.
All the apt-get update/upgrades were correctly trying to modify the new /boot and creating/installing new kernels, etc. but that didn't matter at system startup as it still was booting from the old /boot. I manually mounted the old /boot and verified that it infact had all the boot, grub config that the system was using.

The fdisk command showed an '*' on the old /boot (/dev/sda1) So I first turned off the boot flag and enabled it on the new /boot (/dev/sdb1) but that didn't help. Then when I ran "grub-install /dev/sdb" (note the whole disk and not sdb1) after that magically everything worked correctly.
Since it was a VM, I had the luxury to make one change and test and revert back to the snapshot and start over.